# Trigger related projects leads

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup

I am new to the salesforce platform and am looking for some guidance. I have read a bit about triggers and was wondering if it would be possible to create one for the following case:

- I have a file uploading daily using Jitterbit that imports projects and leads from ConstructConnect and this is working great.
- I am now stuck trying to figure out how I can automatically relate these newly added records to each other or existing ones.
- I have another object called `ProjectLeads` which is suppose to join the two objects. Leads related to a project and vice versa. Jitterbit uses the source file to map fields to the salesforce object but the issue is the `SFDCProjectID` that is created in salesforce upon inserting new records and a `CreatedById` lookup field in the Lead Object which the FTP file cannot map too.

Is there any documentation somebody could point me towards, whether it was related in any way to my question or triggers in general (hopefully with some code examples)

Comment: Take a look at [Flow](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/flow-basics/get-started-with-flows), it's a no-code way of handling your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to populate the SFDCProjectId/CreatedId using a batch process.

1. Create another input for updating the Leads with the associated SFDCProjectId and CreatedId to build the relationship.
2. If you have process of automatically Identifying these relationship across leads with a business Logic; implement the logic on Apex/Flow etc and run those as batch apex or schedule-trigger flow.